# NestJs Typeorm MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, nestjs, datasource, typeorm

trying to connect via NestJs and TypeORM to an MSSQL Express instance:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  name: "mssql_drink",
  type: "mssql",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 1433,
  username: "report",
  password: "report",
  database: "drink",
  schema: "dbo",
  extra: {
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    validateConnection: false,
    options: {
      instanceName: "SQLEXPRESS",
      fallbackToDefaultDb: true 
    },
  },
  synchronize: true,  
  entities: [Rechnungendrink],
}),
```

But I'm just getting:

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms
```

Any ideas what could be the problem? Both are running on the same maschine.

Comment: Use an instance name, or use a port, don't use both. If you know that a named instance is listening on a particular port then use that port in preference to the instance name: instance names add a layer of fragility with clients needing to use the SQL Server Resolution Protocol to communicate with the SQL Browser service over udp/1434, resolve the instance name to a TCP port number, and finally connect to the resolved port number.

Comment: After 24 hours of reading documentation and searching on the web, your comment saved me man! thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Got it now working. Had an issue with the ports.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).